# The method proprietaryEvaluate(String, Class<String>, PageContext, null) is undefined for the type PageContextImpl

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl

This is my first time to use java servlets and JSP. I have been desperately trying to send a list from a java servlet to a JSP page...with no luck.. :(

I know the error has to be something with the way I am reading the data in the jsp page, but after viewing many samples online, i cannot find what is the problem.

here is my servlet and jsp code

any advice would be greatly appreciated

**class**

```
   public class data {

        private String url_hb;
        private String brand_hb;
        private String descr_hb;
        private String dist_hb;
        private String partno_hb;
        private String price_hb;

        public void set_url(String url_hb) {
            this.url_hb = url_hb;
        }

        public void set_brand(String brand_hb) {
            this.brand_hb = brand_hb;
        }

        public void set_descr(String descr_hb) {
            this.descr_hb = descr_hb;
        }

        public void set_dist(String dist_hb) {
            this.dist_hb = dist_hb;
        }

        public void set_partno(String partno_hb) {
            this.partno_hb = partno_hb;
        }

        public void set_price(String price_hb) {
            this.price_hb = price_hb;
        }

        //
        public String get_url() {
            return url_hb;
        }

        public String get_brand() {
            return brand_hb;
        }

        public String get_descr() {
            return descr_hb;
        }

        public String get_dist() {
            return dist_hb;
        }

        public String get_partno() {
            return partno_hb;
        }

        public String get_price() {
            return price_hb;
        }

    }
```

**servlet**

```
 List<data> list = new ArrayList<data>();
            data row0 = new data();
            row0.set_url("testurl");
            row0.set_brand("my brand");
            row0.set_descr("my des");
            row0.set_dist("my dis");
            row0.set_partno("det12321");
            row0.set_price("50000");
            row0.set_url("www.com");       

            list.add(row0);

            ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
            RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/results.jsp");
            request.setAttribute("list", list);
            rd.forward(request, response);
```

**jsp**

```
 <c:forEach items="${list}" var="r">
                <tr>      
                    <td>${record.price_hb}</td>
                </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

**My error:**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 63 in the jsp file: /results.jsp
The method proprietaryEvaluate(String, Class<String>, PageContext, null) is undefined for the type PageContextImpl
60:             
61:             <c:forEach items="${list}" var="r">
62:                 <tr>      
63:                     <td>${record.price_hb}</td>
64:                 </tr>
65:             </c:forEach>
66:
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your var from `r` to `record` then your code will run I think. because this taglib library will fetch `object` from `list` and put it into `var ="record"` So, access your each result using  `${record.price_hb}`

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.list}" var="record">
                    <tr>      
                        <td>${record.price_hb}</td>
                    </tr>
     </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thats what my answer also

Comment: Now see the difference @KalaiarasanManimaran. I am using ${requestScope.list} which is much safer way to use taglib.